# jScrollPane: horizontal scrollbar shifts left when dragging the jspDrag bit in Webkit

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit, jscrollpane

I've got a Webkit specific problem when using the horizontal scrollbar in combination with an anchor tag. An example of the problem is shown here: http://www.splinterarchitecten.nl/wonen-combinatie/

Please take the following steps:

1. Use Chrome (I'm using version 24.0.1312.57) or Safari (5.1.7) to go to the given address.
2. Use the scrollbar to scroll to an image beyond the first three.
3. Click on that image.
4. Click on the 'overzicht' link in the bottom right corner.
5. This returns you to the overview, with the clicked image on the left (anchor tag functionality).
6. Grab the scrollbar drag bit and move it to the left.
7. The whole scrollbar dissapears behind the logo on the left.
8. Refresh the page, the scrollbar behaves itself.

The CSS is included before the javascript. I've tried 'autoReinitialise: true', which made no difference. I now use the following code:

```
if ( window.location.hash ) {
    api.scrollToElement( $j( window.location.hash ), 1 );
}
```

which seems to help some (at least the scrollbar is shown in its proper place initially), but the problem with the dragging is still there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Vivienne

Comment: Just tested this out in Chrome 25.0.1364.152, with no problems.  None in Safari 5.1.2, either.

Comment: Tested in Chrome 25.0.1364.160 with no problems.

Comment: 26.0.1384.2 no problems. Cannot reproduce (I use that often with my QA team - ~devilish grin~)

Comment: I'm still seeing the problem, even using Chrome 25.0.1364.160. Although I must admit that I've had to repeat steps 2 through 6 to make it wonky (the first time the scrollbar behaved fine).

Comment: Tested with Chrome 25.0.1364.172 on Mac OSx 10.7.5, no problem. On Safari 6.0.2 (7536.26.17), I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have any newer information about your bug?

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround**

I've been playing with your scrollbar, and the only thing I got is that the positioning of the scrollbar weirdly seems to depends on the scroll of your `jspPane`. Cannot figure why.

Anyway, if you can control the way `jsscrollpane` initialize the pane, it seems that if you move the `jspHorizontalBar` to make it a direct child of `tiascrollpanehor` like that :

```
<div id="tiascrollpanehor" class="scroll-pane jspScrollable" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 525px; " tabindex="0"> 
    <div class="jspHorizontalBar">
    <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 525px; height: 439px; ">
    ....
```

It positions itself well **but** is not user controllable. To fix that, add

```
.jspHorizontalBar{
    ...
    z-index:2;
}
```

I still can't explain why it's behaving like that, but I hope this will fix that bug for you (as I can't modify CSS and HTML structure before page rendering).